# Offline Backup RDF(Virtuoso) Database And restore this database with striping

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

Now in virtuoso.db file striping is not enable. and I want to restore this data with striping functionality. there has to one way to convert data with striping.so please tell me the complete way to do this so i can convert my data.

Thanx

Comment: What is your question?  You said there is a way to do this so what's your problem here?  Did it not work, is there a reason you can't use the solution you know exists?

Comment: it didn't work. So please if u have a solution then tell me. And Thanx I have edited my question.

Comment: Your question now makes less sense than before.  If the way you know about didn't work then include the error message(s) you encountered.  I'd also suggest asking this question direct to Virtuoso support (virtuoso-users@lists.sf.net for open source edition support)

Comment: See This is the text from OPenlink Virtuoso:   "Databases that were created without striping cannot automatically be restarted with striping. You can convert a non-striping database to striping by dumping the contents of the database to a transaction file and replaying it with striping enabled. An on-line backup made with backup_online () can be restored on a database with a different striping configuration as long as the total number of pages is no less than the number of pages of the backed up database"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximate steps are as suggested in the documentation snippet you quoted.  (It helps to include links to the source pages, when you post snippets like this -- so we [I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)] can adjust content if necessary...)

1. Dump the database, using your preferred backup method
   (`backup_online()`, `+backup-dump`, `+crash-dump`).
2. Move/remove the existing `.db` file.
3. Edit the `INI` file, setting striping as desired.
4. Restore the `.db` from the backup `.trx` dump using the function appropriate to your dump (`+restore-backup`, `+restore-crash-dump`).

Exact steps for your deployment cannot be usefully provided here.

For the future -- questions specifically regarding Virtuoso are generally best raised on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).